# Setting associations for unlisted extensions in Windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-10

This feels like a really stupid question, but here goes.  I'm trying to associate VLC player as the default program with which to open .flv files on a machine running Windows 10.  However, when I go to "Choose default apps by file type" in Settings, I don't see the .flv extension listed, nor do I see any way to add an unlisted extension.  It used to be that I could just find an .flv file in windows explorer, choose "Open with", choose VLC, and check a box that would make this the default, but that box appears to be gone now as well.

So: how do I set a default program for an extension that's not listed in the "Default apps" settings?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right-click a .flv file, open its properties and in the tab "General", see "Opens with" and the "Change" Button behind. Click it and select the vlc.exe in its install directory.

The program you select there will apply to all files of that filetype.

Comment: Thanks!  Knew it was something simple, but I'm not used to Windows 10.